# Only One Session Variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

i've got a Problem that i can't solve and i can't find any related solutions on SO or somewhere else, unfortunatly.

Basically i just want to send 3 Arrays with Data to the Client Javascript. Its working fine for 2 Arrays, but the 3rd one becomes empty when i refresh the page in browser, and i don't know why.

heres the related code;

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
ssn = req.session;
ssn.anlagen = [];
var Betreiber = {
    TableName: "XXX",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#usr = :user",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#usr": "User",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":user": req.body.name
    },
};

docClient.query(Betreiber, function(err, data) {
    if (data.Count == 0 || req.body.passwort != data.Items[0].Passwort) {
        res.render(__dirname + '/views/login', {text: "Der Nutzername oder das Passwort sind falsch! Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut."});
    }
    else if (req.body.passwort == data.Items[0].Passwort) {
        anlagenarray = [];
        ssn.user = data.Items[0].User; // WORKS FINE
        ssn.admin = data.Items[0].Admin; // WORKS FINE
        if (ssn.admin == false) { // Normal
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Items[0].Anlagen.length; i++) {
                ssn.ident = data.Items[0].Anlagen[Object.keys(data.Items[0].Anlagen)[i]];
                var Anlagenbezeichnung = {
                    TableName: "SCR-Anlagen",
                    KeyConditionExpression: "#ident = :id",
                    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                        "#ident": "Id",
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":id": ssn.ident
                    },
                };

                docClient.query(Anlagenbezeichnung, function(err, data) {
                  ssn.anlagen = data.Items[0].Bezeichnung // this Variable gets "[]" after refresh
                   ssn.anlagen.sort();
                });
            }
        }
```

Heres the Code to send Arrays to the Client Side JS;

```
app.post("/anlagen", function(req, res) {
    if (ssn.user) {
        res.send({
            name: ssn.user, // WORKS
            adminstatus: ssn.admin, // WORKS
            bezeichnungen: ssn.anlagen // [] after Page refresh
        });
    }
    else {
        res.render(__dirname + '/views/login');
    }
});
```

I just can't find any solution for this. i literally tried everything, but i keep getting this error.
detailed solution approaches highly appreciated.

it's my first try on backend web development, don't be too hard, if my complete code is total bullshit^^

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there code missing? I do not see where you set the key "Bezeichnung"

Comment: theres a lot of code missing. which isn't related to the problem. i only put in the related code.
"data.Items[0].Bezeichnung" is data from a dynamo database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the Problem by myself.

If you have a similar Problem. Just put `req.session.save();`  inside the query.

like this:

```
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {   
req.session.bezeichnung.push([data.Items[0].Bezeichnung,data.Items[0].Id]);      
req.session.save();
});
```

This will make the Variable accessible outside of the query scope.